# Change variable in integration with symmetry

Tags: gr.group-theory, measure-theory, integration, symmetric-functions

Not sure if I can ask such fundamental problem here.

Let

1. $G$ be a finite group, $\sigma \in G$. Consider linear group actions fo $G$ on $\mathbb{R}^n$.
2. $\sigma(K)=\{x\in \mathbb{R}^n: \sigma^{-1}(x) \in K\}$.
3. $K\subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ be $G$-invariant, i.e., $\bigcap_{\sigma\in G} \sigma(K) = K$.

Suppose

1. $K\subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$  is $G$-invariant.
2. polynomial $h(x)\in \mathbb{R}[X]$ is $G$-invariant, i.e., $h(\sigma^{-1}(x))=h(x), \, \forall \sigma \in G$.

Note that

1. Let $\mathcal{P}(K)$ be the set of probability measures supported on $K$.
2. For $\mu\in \mathcal{P}(K)$, $\sigma^{-1}(K)\subseteq K, \, \forall\sigma$. $\mu$ is $G$-invariant if $\mu (B) = \mu(\sigma^{-1}(B))$ for any Borel set $B\subseteq K$.

Consider the following

\begin{equation}
     \begin{aligned}
     \int_K h(x) \mu(dx) &=_1 \int_K h(\sigma(x)) \mu(dx) \\ 
     &=_2  \int_K h(x) \mu(\sigma^{-1}(dx))
     \end{aligned}
 \end{equation}

1. comes from the fact that $h(x)$ is $G$-invariant and $G$ is a group.

> My questions are

1. Is the changing variable of step 2. correct?  (Note that $\sigma(K)=K,\, \forall \sigma \in G$ from assumption.)
2. Can I say that since the $2$nd equality holds for all $dx$, so $$\mu(dx) = \mu(\sigma^{-1}(dx)),$$ i.e., $\mu$ is $G$-invariant.

I appreciate any help or comment!

Comment: Your assumption 3 looks different from saying $\sigma(K)=K$ for all $\sigma\in G$.

Comment: @AbdelmalekAbdesselam From my research, $K = \{x: g_j(x) \geq 0, j=1,\ldots, m\}$ and $g_j^{\sigma} = g_j$. I just prove that we can have $\sigma(K) = K$ for all $\sigma \in G$, if $G$ is a symmetric group. This is because its representation in $\mathbb{R}^n$ is an invertible matrix. So $\sigma(K) = K$.

Comment: Use $\cup$ instead of $\cap$ in your assumption 3, otherwise what you said there is not correct.

Comment: @AbdelmalekAbdesselam Actually it should be $\cap$, which I check the paper I read.

Comment: then the paper is wrong